# What is the syntax for partially specialising a template based on the number of parameters a template template parameter takes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++, template-templates

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename>
struct One {};

template<typename, typename>
struct Two {};

template<template<typename...> class TTP, typename...>
struct SS;

#ifdef    TEST_TTP
    template<template<typename> class OneParam,
             typename... Ts>
    struct SS<OneParam, Ts...> {};

    template<template<typename, typename> class TwoParam,
             typename... Ts>
    struct SS<TwoParam, Ts...> {};
#else  // TEST_TTP
    template<template<typename> class OneParam,
             typename TParam>
    struct SS<OneParam, TParam> {};

    template<template<typename, typename> class TwoParam,
             typename TParam1,
             typename TParam2>
    struct SS<TwoParam, TParam1, TParam2> {};
#endif // TEST_TTP

int main() {
    SS<One, int>       ssoi;
    SS<Two, int, int> sstii;
}
```

This code will compile properly on Clang, GCC, and MSVC, if `TEST_TTP` isn't defined.  However, if it *is* defined...

- The code compiles properly on GCC, indicating that it recognises that `OneParam` and `TwoParam` are distinct from `TTP` in the primary template.
- Clang fails to recognise that `OneParam` specialises `TTP`, causing it to emit two errors (the first being that the partial specialisation doesn't specialise any template parameters, and the second being that `OneParam` conflicts with the previously-declared template template parameter).  It then emits similar errors for `TwoParam` (the first is identical, while the second says that the template template parameter has too many parameters), and an error for each instantiation of `SS` (because it considers the template to be undefined), for a total of 6 errors.
- MSVC emits similar errors to Clang, but more concisely: It emits C3855 (`OneParam` is incompatible with the primary template), and a C2079 (variable uses undefined type) for each instantiation of `SS`, for a total of 3 errors.

Demonstrated live [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f145f13504935246).

---

From my testing:

**GCC allows a template with a template template parameter which takes a variadic parameter pack to be partially specialised based solely on the number of parameters that template template parameter takes. Clang and MSVC do not.**

```
template<template<typename...>        class T> struct S;
template<template<typename>           class T> struct S<T> {}; // Only works with GCC.
template<template<typename, typename> class T> struct S<T> {}; // Only works with GCC.
```

**Clang and MSVC are fine with this if other parameters are also specialised, however.**

```
template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts> struct S;

template<template<typename> class T,
         typename TParam>
struct S<T, TParam> {};

template<template<typename, typename> class T,
         typename TParam1,
         typename TParam2>
struct S<T, TParam1, TParam2> {};
```

It would thus appear that either the former isn't legal C++, or it isn't properly supported by Clang and MSVC.  So, the question is this:

**Considering this, what is the proper, legal syntax for partially specialising a template, which contains a template template parameter, based on the number of parameters that template template parameter takes? If there is no legal syntax for this, is supporting it a GCC extension and/or bug?**

<sup>If a full record of the tests I performed, along with the original example which prompted this question, are desired, please see the edit history.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: your code is valid, but no compiler handles it correctly; even those that accept it (gcc and ICC (Intel C++ Compiler)) do so inconsistently or for the wrong reason.

The correct reasoning is as follows:

1. A variadic template template parameter can [be deduced to a single-argument template template parameter, and vice versa](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#3). gcc is the only compiler to get this correct.
2. A single-argument template is [more specialized than a variadic template](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#9). All modern compilers get this right.
3. [Accordingly](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#10), a function template taking a single-argument template template parameter is more specialized than a function template taking a variadic template template parameter. The only compiler that appears to get this correct is ICC, but only because it gets (1) wrong.
4. [Accordingly](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.order#1), a class template taking a single-argument template template parameter is more specialized than a class template taking a variadic template template parameter. ICC and gcc appear to get this correct, but in the former case because it gets (1) wrong, and gcc inconsistently with (3).

Conclusion: you are using the proper, legal syntax; but you are likely to need workarounds for non-compliant compilers. Even when your code compiles I would **recommend using `static_assert`** to verify that the expected function overload or class template partial specialization has been selected.

---

#### Full analysis

Per [**[temp.class.order]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.order), we partially order class template partial specializations by rewriting to overloaded function templates:

```
// rewrite corresponding to primary
template<template<typename...> class TTP, typename... Ts>
int f(SS<TTP, Ts...>) { return 0; } // #0

// rewrite corresponding to specialization
template<template<typename> class OneParam, typename... Ts>
int f(SS<OneParam, Ts...>) { return 1; } // #1

int ssoi = f(SS<One, int>{});
```

As expected, clang rejects this rewrite, claiming the call to `f` as ambiguous, as does MSVC; gcc inconsistently rejects this rewrite even though it accepted the original class template partial specialization. ICC accepts this rewrite and initializes `ssoi` to `1`, corresponding to the `OneParam` specialization `#1`.

Now we can determine which compiler is correct by following the [rules for partial ordering of function templates](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order) (**[temp.func.order]**). We can see that the call to `f` at the initialization of `ssoi` can call either `#0` or `#1`, so to determine which is more specialized we must synthesize template arguments and attempt to perform type deduction:

```
// #1 -> #0
template<template<typename...> class TTP, typename... Ts>
int f0(SS<TTP, Ts...>);
template<typename> class OneParam1;
int ssoi0 = f0(SS<OneParam1>{});

// #0 -> #1
template<template<typename> class OneParam, typename... Ts>
int f1(SS<OneParam, Ts...>);
template<typename...> class TTP0;
int ssoi1 = f1(SS<TTP0>{});
```

Note that per **[temp.func.order]**/5 we do not synthesize arguments corresponding to `Ts...`.

Deduction in `#1 -> #0` succeeds (`TTP := OneParam1; Ts... := {}`), as expected (`#1` is the rewrite corresponding to a partial specialization of the class template of which `#0` is the rewrite).

Deduction in `#0 -> #1` succeeds (`OneParam := TTP0; Ts... := {}`) under gcc and MSVC. clang (inconsistently) and ICC reject `f1`, stating that `TTP0` cannot be deduced to `OneParam` (clang: "candidate template ignored: substitution failure : template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter").

So we must first determine whether the deduction `#0 -> #1` is indeed feasible. We can look at a simpler, equivalent case:

```
template<template<class> class P> class X { };
template<class...> class C { };
X<C> xc;
```

This is accepted by gcc, and rejected by MSVC (inconsistently), clang and ICC. However, gcc is correct to accept this per [**[temp.arg.template]**/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#3).

Next we must determine whether `#1` is more specialized than `#0`, or whether they are ambiguous in terms of ordering. Per **[temp.deduct.partial]**/10 we consider the types in `#0` and `#1` turn by turn; per **[temp.arg.template]**/4 we can rewrite `OneParam` and `TTP` to function templates, simultaneously :

```
template<typename...> class X1;
template<typename> class X2;
template<typename PP> int f(X1<PP>); // #2
template<typename... PP> int f(X1<PP...>); // #3
template<typename PP> int g(X2<PP>); // #4
template<typename... PP> int g(X2<PP...>); // #5
```

We now [partial order](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order) the rewritten `f` and `g` overloads, passing through **[temp.deduct.partial]** and **[temp.deduct.type]** to determine that per the [tie-breaker for variadics](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#9) `#1` is more specialized than `#0`.

Comment: That's a very in-depth answer.  I hadn't even thought to try ICC or other compilers, and I very much appreciate the recommendation of always verifying it with a `static_assert` because of how much trouble compilers have with it.  Thank you very much.